# how to run the triggers on the uncommitted data in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is a number range defined in my database table.(1000-1999),(from = 1000, to = 1999)
I am trying to split this number range as two part below:

```
part1 : 1000-1001
part2 : 1002-1999
```

There is a uniqueness check(trigger checks intersection of the number ranges after insertion to the database table.) in the DB so I should provide the appropriate data in order to perform this execution.

Executed scripts are below for split operation :

```
UPDATE 1000-1999 as 1000-1001
INSERT 1002-1999
COMMIT;
```

While executing the above pl sql blocks, INSERT operation has been caught by trigger which runs on the database table.

Why the trigger is running although I have updated the existing row before insert operation?

How can we handle this situation?

Comment: Triggers and Commit are independent of each other. Triggers fire on an event while COMMIT ends a transaction. That way a trigger will always run on un-committed data. What you are asking is not clear. Could you elaborate?

Comment: In my case, I am starting a transaction and executing the above pl sql commands(update and then insert) and I am committing the transaction. Before committing my transaction it is failing during the insertion to the DB cause of the existing trigger has worked.

Comment: The trigger SHOULD run on each of your statements. That is normal. But from your description, that should not be a problem, Since you get an error, something else is amiss. Please provide the source of the trigger (and maybe the table definition), so we can look more closely.

Comment: You say that it is failing. What is failing? Are you getting any error? What does the trigger do exactly? Is it statement level or row level? Before or after? What is your update trying to do? If you can provide some more details it'll help us help you. Right now nothing is clear and we can only shoot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue after deleted the trigger from the database and written a stored procedure which handles 1) update 2)trigger job 3)add job.

Thanks for your help.